# Why am I getting an error for index 0 out of bounds for length 0 when trying to print separate rows of stars?

Tags: java

I expected it to print the stars. The results were that it printed the stars in the way I wanted, but I got an error when testing saying, "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0".
Code:

```
public class Printer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // You can test the method here
        int[] array = {5, 1, 3, 4, 2};
        printArrayInStars(array);
   }

    public static void printArrayInStars(int[] array) {
        // Write some code in here
   
         int i = 1;
        while (i<=array[0]) {
            System.out.print("*");
            i++;           
        }
        System.out.println("");
    
        int a = 1;
        while (a<=array[1]) {
            System.out.print("*");
            a++;           
        }
        System.out.println("");
    
        int b = 1;
        while (b<=array[2]) {
            System.out.print("*");
            b++;           
        }
        System.out.println("");
    
        int c = 1;
        while (c<=array[3]) {
            System.out.print("*");
            c++;           
        }
        System.out.println("");

        int d = 1;
        while (d<=array[4]) {
            System.out.print("*");
            d++;           
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Results:

---

- 

---

---

**

Comment: Might want to rearrange how you loop through this.

Comment: Your code is running fine on my end. I am getting the following output -- *****
   *
   ***
   ****
   **

Comment: Can you tell us more details how you are testing your code?

Comment: @Numery I am using tmc beans and when i click run project it gives me the correct output, but when i click run tests locally, i get that error.

Comment: Please provide us few more information. What code is there on your test file? Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to loop an array and print array[i] amount of * there are better ways but this is probably the simplest one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // You can test the method here
    int[] array = {5, 1, 3, 4, 2};
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        printArrayInStars(array[i]);
    }
}

public static void printArrayInStars(int n) {
    // Write some code in here
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Outputs

```
*****
*
***
****
**
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: You can see this snip]

buddy here is the picture, I posted as you can see no runtime error,
you might changing your compiler, or copy and paste to new java file  and run it again

Answer (score -1):

```
class star
{
    public void series()
    {
        String [] a = {"*","*","*","*"};
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<4;j++)
            {   
                System.out.printf(a[j]);
            }System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        star s = new star();
        s.series();
    }
}
```

output will be
4 line of stars,
each line will have 4 stars

if expect something else, please clear your question. n what manner you wanna print stars.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Stop directly posting the solution. Instead, consider explaining.

Comment: well buddy i tried to run your program, there is no error it.

Comment: The question was `Why am I getting an error for index 0 out of bounds for length 0 when trying to print separate rows of stars?`. Your answer hardly attempts to explain why, and `output will be 4 line of stars, each line will have 4 stars

if expect something else, please clear your question. n what manner you wanna print stars` doesn't really help.

Comment: alright buddy, if you don;t have problem with program,  and you are here to know why the error of out of bound appear. Then it is very simple, Your program has no error as u can see in new answer. Out of bound appear when you try to fetch or enter the values in array more then the defined size. You did not  try to fetch the value from array, So it is not possible to get error. You are just comparing the values of array with values of different variable. And i am so sorry i didn't got your question at first time. and in picture the output is of your program without any modification.

Comment: When i run the code it works, but when i test it, i get that error. It says index 0 is out of bounds, but there is a value at index 0 of the array, so I am confused on why im getting the error.

Comment: This question doesn't answer the question. -1